# A riddle in foreign language

Tags: riddle

> I am true and a liar,
>   You can’t touch me,
>   But you do use me,
>   I work when off or on,
>   Which most rely upon,
>   Without me, there would be,
>   no processes to see.

What am I?

Comment: I will add a hint if anybody asks for one. No cheap tricks here.

Comment: If you can put a (hidden) hint in the title, you can get rid of the generic & bland "this is a riddle" title and possibly get a cooler title. :)

Comment: Anton - Good idea! But now that you pointed that out it may give it away lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a:

> Binary value/flag

I am true and a liar,

> True and false (1/0)

You can’t touch me,

> You cannot touch electronic data

But you do use me,
I work when off or on,

> Binary values are used as both true and false

Which most rely upon,
Without me, there would be,
no processes to see.

> 0's and 1's (binary values) are used as machine code to run all computer software.

Comment: You got it! Hopefully it wasn't too easy :)

Comment: I hadn't refreshed and didn't realize that Reti had this, partially - oops.

Comment: You can go ahead and move the mark to Reti's since he apparently had it while I was typing this.  I don't care.

Answer (score 4):

You are a

> transistor switch.

I am true and a liar

> Binary has two states, which as boolean are true and false.

You can’t touch me

> Not a convincing answer, but the swithes we use for computers are too small for us to practically touch.

But you do use me

> Computers rely on them and we use those every day.

I work when off or on

> No matter its state, it contributes to something.

Which most rely upon

> Same comment from above how we use computers for everything.

Without me, there would be,
no processes to see.

> Another unconvincing answer. Without them, computers wouldn't work and no programs/processes would run. However, we could always substitute them for something else.

Title hint

> If the title includes a hint on its own, it could be referring to binary, which is the computer language. Kind of. Boy, this answer started off well and took a dive.

Comment: You got the answer but it's not the answer you wrote.

Comment: @Reti43 I have a hunch it is the first clue he is referring to

Answer (score 3):

I think it is:

> Light

I am true and a liar,

> Acts as both a particle and a wave

You can’t touch me,
 But you do use me,

> Can't touch it, but need it to see

I work when off or on,

> Not sure

Which most rely upon,

> Everyone but the blind need light to get through the day

Without me, there would be,
 no processes to see.

> Without light, we could not see anything

Comment: Good guess! But not quite it. The answer will fit all of the lines of the riddle. Like you mentioned, light doesn't work when off. ;)